Concurrent read/writes in SQLite corrupting read results?
I have a multithreaded app that uses a SQLite DB for persistent storage.  The application uses one persistent connection.  It prepares the statements at startup and after each rollback. It's also using journal_model=WAL to help with the concurrent access.
I'm finding that when my listUsers() function is called concurrently that occasionally the results seem to leak between calls.  I know there's 100 users but sometimes the results are 100+ and I think it's because the sqlite3_step on one thread is pulling results from the sqlite3_step that could have been called on another thread.
Is that possible?
Also, I've tried wrapping the listUsers() in a transaction but occasionally it will throw errors that a transaction is being started inside another transaction.  Again, I think this is because two threads are sharing the same DB connection.
Is there a common solution to this issue?  One connection per thread?  I'm not so concerned with the occasional locked database or long waits, it's just invalid results that are worrisome.
If it's helpful, my listUsers() looks like
std::vector<User> listUsers()
{
    char* err = 0;
    auto users = std::vector<User>();
    sqlite3_reset(list_user_stmt);
    beginTransaction();
    while (SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(list_user_stmt))
    {
        auto id = sqlite3_column_int(list_user_stmt, 0);
        auto name = sqlite3_column_text(list_user_stmt, 1);
        users.push_back(User{id, name});
    }
    commitTransaction();
    return users;
}


Impossible to tell without seeing the offending code. If you have a data race, the program has undefined behavior, and then you cannot expect any results. If you call your listUsers from different threads, then obviously you have a race on list_user_stmt (whatever it is), and possibly on some SQL library internals.

The prepared statement list_user_stmt is definitely shared.  Is that not safe?  If that's the case, I guess I can either prepare the statement as needed or put a lock around the listUsers()

Depends on the access/open mode of the DB see Using SQLite In Multi-Threaded Applications are you using Multi-thread or Serialized ?  If Multi-thread then you can't share DB connections (and any derived objects) between threads.

You can not use the same connection from multiple threads simultaneously. SQLite the database is safe for concurrent access, but a single connection is not (well as far as I know it will be 'thread safe' in the sense that it's not actually going to corrupt any data, but it will not behave like you'd want in this case – in particular there is no transaction isolation across a single connection, as that doesn't really make any sense). If you do need to access the thread from multiple threads at the same time, you either put a mutex on the connection and only have one thread access the database at any one time (usually not needed for SQLite, but if e.g. you cache some results at application level you might need to do that to keep your cached view consistent), have a connection per thread or use a connection pool as a reasonable middle ground if you have a lot of threads.
